# Fedex Create International Shipment issue

Tags: php, fedex

I am trying to create the international shipment for fedex I am using following schema

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:q0="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v21" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<soapenv:Body>

<q0:ProcessShipmentRequest>

  <q0:WebAuthenticationDetail>

    <q0:UserCredential>

      <q0:Key>xxxxx</q0:Key>

      <q0:Password>xxxxx</q0:Password>

    </q0:UserCredential>

  </q0:WebAuthenticationDetail>

  <q0:ClientDetail>

    <q0:AccountNumber>xxxxx</q0:AccountNumber>

    <q0:MeterNumber>xxxx</q0:MeterNumber>

  </q0:ClientDetail>

  <q0:TransactionDetail>

    <q0:CustomerTransactionId>Express Intl Shipment Example</q0:CustomerTransactionId>

  </q0:TransactionDetail>

  <q0:Version>

    <q0:ServiceId>ship</q0:ServiceId>

    <q0:Major>21</q0:Major>

    <q0:Intermediate>0</q0:Intermediate>

    <q0:Minor>0</q0:Minor>

  </q0:Version>

  <q0:RequestedShipment>

    <q0:ShipTimestamp>2018-02-21T18:42:46.286Z</q0:ShipTimestamp>

    <q0:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</q0:DropoffType>

    <q0:ServiceType>INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY</q0:ServiceType>

    <q0:PackagingType>FEDEX_SMALL_BOX</q0:PackagingType>

    <q0:Shipper>

      <q0:Contact>

        <q0:PersonName>John Doe</q0:PersonName>

        <q0:CompanyName>FedEx</q0:CompanyName>

        <q0:PhoneNumber>9015551234</q0:PhoneNumber>

      </q0:Contact>

      <q0:Address>

        <q0:StreetLines>3610 Hacks Cross Road</q0:StreetLines>

        <q0:StreetLines>First Floor</q0:StreetLines>

        <q0:City>Memphis</q0:City>

        <q0:StateOrProvinceCode>TN</q0:StateOrProvinceCode>

        <q0:PostalCode>38125</q0:PostalCode>

        <q0:CountryCode>US</q0:CountryCode>

      </q0:Address>

    </q0:Shipper>

    <q0:Recipient>

      <q0:Contact>

        <q0:PersonName>Joe Customer</q0:PersonName>

        <q0:CompanyName>ABC Widget Co</q0:CompanyName>

        <q0:PhoneNumber>4455551234</q0:PhoneNumber>

      </q0:Contact>

      <q0:Address>

        <q0:StreetLines>1234 Main Street</q0:StreetLines>

        <q0:StreetLines>Suite 200</q0:StreetLines>

        <q0:City>Nuneaton</q0:City>

        <q0:PostalCode>Cv114al</q0:PostalCode>

        <q0:CountryCode>GB</q0:CountryCode>

        <q0:Residential>false</q0:Residential>

      </q0:Address>

    </q0:Recipient>

    <q0:ShippingChargesPayment>

      <q0:PaymentType>SENDER</q0:PaymentType>

      <q0:Payor>

        <q0:ResponsibleParty>

          <q0:AccountNumber>xxxxxx</q0:AccountNumber>

          <q0:Contact/>

        </q0:ResponsibleParty>

      </q0:Payor>

    </q0:ShippingChargesPayment>

    <q0:CustomsClearanceDetail>

      <q0:DutiesPayment>

        <q0:PaymentType>SENDER</q0:PaymentType>

        <q0:Payor>

          <q0:ResponsibleParty>

            <q0:AccountNumber>xxxxx</q0:AccountNumber>

            <q0:Contact/>

          </q0:ResponsibleParty>

        </q0:Payor>

      </q0:DutiesPayment>

      <q0:DocumentContent>DOCUMENTS_ONLY</q0:DocumentContent>

      <q0:CustomsValue>

        <q0:Currency>USD</q0:Currency>

        <q0:Amount>1.00</q0:Amount>

      </q0:CustomsValue>

      <q0:Commodities>

        <q0:NumberOfPieces>1</q0:NumberOfPieces>

        <q0:Description>Bank Statements</q0:Description>

        <q0:CountryOfManufacture>US</q0:CountryOfManufacture>

        <q0:Weight>

          <q0:Units>LB</q0:Units>

          <q0:Value>1.0</q0:Value>

        </q0:Weight>

        <q0:Quantity>1</q0:Quantity>

        <q0:QuantityUnits>pcs</q0:QuantityUnits>

        <q0:CustomsValue>

          <q0:Currency>USD</q0:Currency>

          <q0:Amount>1.00</q0:Amount>

        </q0:CustomsValue>

      </q0:Commodities>

    </q0:CustomsClearanceDetail>

    <q0:LabelSpecification>

      <q0:LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</q0:LabelFormatType>

      <q0:ImageType>PDF</q0:ImageType>

      <q0:LabelStockType>PAPER_4X6</q0:LabelStockType>

      <q0:CustomerSpecifiedDetail>

        <q0:MaskedData>CUSTOMS_VALUE</q0:MaskedData>

        <q0:MaskedData>DUTIES_AND_TAXES_PAYOR_ACCOUNT_NUMBER</q0:MaskedData>

        <q0:MaskedData>SHIPPER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER</q0:MaskedData>

        <q0:MaskedData>TRANSPORTATION_CHARGES_PAYOR_ACCOUNT_NUMBER</q0:MaskedData>

      </q0:CustomerSpecifiedDetail>

    </q0:LabelSpecification>

    <q0:PackageCount>1</q0:PackageCount>

    <q0:RequestedPackageLineItems>

      <q0:SequenceNumber>1</q0:SequenceNumber>

      <q0:Weight>

        <q0:Units>LB</q0:Units>

        <q0:Value>1.0</q0:Value>

      </q0:Weight>

      <q0:CustomerReferences>

        <q0:CustomerReferenceType>CUSTOMER_REFERENCE</q0:CustomerReferenceType>

        <q0:Value>ref1234</q0:Value>

      </q0:CustomerReferences>

    </q0:RequestedPackageLineItems>

  </q0:RequestedShipment>

</q0:ProcessShipmentRequest>

</soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But whenever I try to create shipment for documents using above schema, It generates following error

"Insufficient information for commodity 1 to complete shipment".

Please let me know if anyone had faced this issue previously.I dont know where I am going wrong.

Comment: _“Insufficient information for commodity 1 to complete shipment”_ - so have you checked the documentation, what data it expects for such a commodity element, and compared that with what you are sending …?

Comment: this is sample request sent by fedex for creating international shipment for sending Documents only, I thought this sample request should directly work

Answer (score 0):

Its actually very late to reply but I just have faced the issue and solved it.
Actually the value of the quantity was 0 with me, that's why i was facing the issue.
you would have something missed in the commodity, go to the "FedEx WebServices Developer Guide", there go to the commodity elements and make sure that you are passing all the parameters.